# Migrating Application from WAS 6.1 to WAS 8.5

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-8

I am migrating applications from WAS 6.1 to WAS 8.5. Existing application works fine in WAS 6.1 but in WAS 8.5 while connecting to a bpm wsdl url, I am getting the following exception. The jar is present in WEB-INF/lib

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.woden.resolver.URIResolver
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:85)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:162)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:65)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:815)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.loadClassPathModules(RepositoryListener.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:71)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadFromClassPath(DeploymentEngine.java:177)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(FileSystemConfigurator.java:135)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:210)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.configureServiceClient(ServiceClient.java:151)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.<init>(ServiceClient.java:144)
```

Comment: Are you bundling third party WebService engine with your application ? Like Axis2 or CXF?

Comment: Yes axis2  and it worked fine in was 6.1 but not works in 8.5 . Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Switch the class loader to local first, parent last.

In application configuration go to:

1. Class loading and update detection
2. Change class loader order to local first
3. Save changes
4. Restart application server

Comment: I have tried that and it is already set to parent last. Restarted but still the same exception occurs. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

For using third party Web service engine you need to set class loader to `parent last` and disable annotation scanning:

> Set the DisableIBMJAXWSEngine property in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF of
>   a WAR file or EJB module to true

See documentation for more details:

- [Using a third-party JAX-WS web services engine](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-3-0-24-10-1&lang=en)